Show a full screen dialogue before showing App Open Ad
According to Google we are not allowed to show banner ad behind an App Open ad or App Open ad should not hide a banner ad behind it. I want to implement a custom dialog saying, "Welcome back to App" 'Loading Ad Please Wait' and show the ad 2-3 seconds later. How may I achieve this?
I have seen it on some apps on Google play.
Since the application's lifecycle functions OnCreate, OnStart & OnResume are called always called when an activity is started, I am unable to achieve the goal by working on these three functions.
For example, if I implement a dialog on the OnResume of an activity A, whenever activity A is going to load OnCreate, OnStart & OnResume of Activity A are going to be called. So, I am not sure how to achieve the said functionality. Same is the case for the code shown below for MyApplication class. Whenever any activity of my project is loaded "Resume Called" is logged in logcat.
public class MyApplication extends Application
    implements ActivityLifecycleCallbacks, DefaultLifecycleObserver {

Boolean resumed = false;
  private AppOpenAdManager appOpenAdManager;
  private Activity currentActivity;
  private static final String TAG = "MyApplication";

  @Override
  public void onCreate() {
    super.onCreate();
    this.registerActivityLifecycleCallbacks(this);

    ProcessLifecycleOwner.get().getLifecycle().addObserver(this);
    appOpenAdManager = new AppOpenAdManager();
  }

  /**
   * DefaultLifecycleObserver method that shows the app open ad when the app moves to foreground.
   */
  @Override
  public void onStart(@NonNull LifecycleOwner owner) {
    DefaultLifecycleObserver.super.onStart(owner);
    // Show the ad (if available) when the app moves to foreground.
    appOpenAdManager.showAdIfAvailable(currentActivity);
  }

  /** ActivityLifecycleCallback methods. */
  @Override
  public void onActivityCreated(@NonNull Activity activity, @Nullable Bundle savedInstanceState) {}

  @Override
  public void onActivityStarted(@NonNull Activity activity) {
    // An ad activity is started when an ad is showing, which could be AdActivity class from Google
    // SDK or another activity class implemented by a third party mediation partner. Updating the
    // currentActivity only when an ad is not showing will ensure it is not an ad activity, but the
    // one that shows the ad.
    if (!appOpenAdManager.isShowingAd) {
      currentActivity = activity;
    }
  }

  @Override
  public void onActivityResumed(@NonNull Activity activity) {
    if (resumed)
    {
        Log.e("AppOpenResume", "Resume called", LENGTH_SHORT).show();
    }
}

  @Override
  public void onActivityPaused(@NonNull Activity activity) {
    resumed = true;
}

  @Override
  public void onActivityStopped(@NonNull Activity activity) {}

  @Override
  public void onActivitySaveInstanceState(@NonNull Activity activity, @NonNull Bundle outState) {}

  @Override
  public void onActivityDestroyed(@NonNull Activity activity) {}

  /**
   * Load an app open ad.
   *
   * @param activity the activity that shows the app open ad
   */
  public void loadAd(@NonNull Activity activity) {
    // We wrap the loadAd to enforce that other classes only interact with MyApplication
    // class.
    appOpenAdManager.loadAd(activity);
  }

  /**
   * Shows an app open ad.
   *
   * @param activity the activity that shows the app open ad
   * @param onShowAdCompleteListener the listener to be notified when an app open ad is complete
   */
  public void showAdIfAvailable(
      @NonNull Activity activity, @NonNull OnShowAdCompleteListener onShowAdCompleteListener) {
    // We wrap the showAdIfAvailable to enforce that other classes only interact with MyApplication
    // class.
    appOpenAdManager.showAdIfAvailable(activity, onShowAdCompleteListener);
  }

  /**
   * Interface definition for a callback to be invoked when an app open ad is complete
   * (i.e. dismissed or fails to show).
   */
  public interface OnShowAdCompleteListener {
    void onShowAdComplete();
  }

  /** Inner class that loads and shows app open ads. */
  private class AppOpenAdManager {

    private static final String LOG_TAG = "AppOpenAdManager";
    private static final String AD_UNIT_ID = "ca-app-pub-3940256099942544/3419835294";

    private final GoogleMobileAdsConsentManager googleMobileAdsConsentManager =
        GoogleMobileAdsConsentManager.getInstance(getApplicationContext());
    private AppOpenAd appOpenAd = null;
    private boolean isLoadingAd = false;
    private boolean isShowingAd = false;

    /** Keep track of the time an app open ad is loaded to ensure you don't show an expired ad. */
    private long loadTime = 0;

    /** Constructor. */
    public AppOpenAdManager() {}

    /**
     * Load an ad.
     *
     * @param context the context of the activity that loads the ad
     */
    private void loadAd(Context context) {
      // Do not load ad if there is an unused ad or one is already loading.
      if (isLoadingAd || isAdAvailable()) {
        return;
      }

      isLoadingAd = true;
      AdRequest request = new AdRequest.Builder().build();
      AppOpenAd.load(
          context,
          AD_UNIT_ID,
          request,
          new AppOpenAdLoadCallback() {
            /**
             * Called when an app open ad has loaded.
             *
             * @param ad the loaded app open ad.
             */
            @Override
            public void onAdLoaded(AppOpenAd ad) {
              appOpenAd = ad;
              isLoadingAd = false;
              loadTime = (new Date()).getTime();

              Log.d(LOG_TAG, "onAdLoaded.");
              Toast.makeText(context, "onAdLoaded", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            }

            /**
             * Called when an app open ad has failed to load.
             *
             * @param loadAdError the error.
             */
            @Override
            public void onAdFailedToLoad(LoadAdError loadAdError) {
              isLoadingAd = false;
              Log.d(LOG_TAG, "onAdFailedToLoad: " + loadAdError.getMessage());
              Toast.makeText(context, "onAdFailedToLoad", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            }
          });
    }

    /** Check if ad was loaded more than n hours ago. */
    private boolean wasLoadTimeLessThanNHoursAgo(long numHours) {
      long dateDifference = (new Date()).getTime() - loadTime;
      long numMilliSecondsPerHour = 3600000;
      return (dateDifference < (numMilliSecondsPerHour * numHours));
    }

    /** Check if ad exists and can be shown. */
    private boolean isAdAvailable() {
      // Ad references in the app open beta will time out after four hours, but this time limit
      // may change in future beta versions. For details, see:
      // https://support.google.com/admob/answer/9341964?hl=en
      return appOpenAd != null && wasLoadTimeLessThanNHoursAgo(4);
    }

    /**
     * Show the ad if one isn't already showing.
     *
     * @param activity the activity that shows the app open ad
     */
    private void showAdIfAvailable(@NonNull final Activity activity) {
      showAdIfAvailable(
          activity,
          new OnShowAdCompleteListener() {
            @Override
            public void onShowAdComplete() {
              // Empty because the user will go back to the activity that shows the ad.
            }
          });
    }

    /**
     * Show the ad if one isn't already showing.
     *
     * @param activity the activity that shows the app open ad
     * @param onShowAdCompleteListener the listener to be notified when an app open ad is complete
     */
    private void showAdIfAvailable(
        @NonNull final Activity activity,
        @NonNull OnShowAdCompleteListener onShowAdCompleteListener) {
      // If the app open ad is already showing, do not show the ad again.
      if (isShowingAd) {
        Log.d(LOG_TAG, "The app open ad is already showing.");
        return;
      }

      // If the app open ad is not available yet, invoke the callback then load the ad.
      if (!isAdAvailable()) {
        Log.d(LOG_TAG, "The app open ad is not ready yet.");
        onShowAdCompleteListener.onShowAdComplete();
        if (googleMobileAdsConsentManager.canRequestAds()) {
          loadAd(currentActivity);
        }
        return;
      }

      Log.d(LOG_TAG, "Will show ad.");

      appOpenAd.setFullScreenContentCallback(
          new FullScreenContentCallback() {
            /** Called when full screen content is dismissed. */
            @Override
            public void onAdDismissedFullScreenContent() {
              // Set the reference to null so isAdAvailable() returns false.
              appOpenAd = null;
              isShowingAd = false;

              Log.d(LOG_TAG, "onAdDismissedFullScreenContent.");
              Toast.makeText(activity, "onAdDismissedFullScreenContent", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

              onShowAdCompleteListener.onShowAdComplete();
              if (googleMobileAdsConsentManager.canRequestAds()) {
                loadAd(activity);
              }
            }

            /** Called when fullscreen content failed to show. */
            @Override
            public void onAdFailedToShowFullScreenContent(AdError adError) {
              appOpenAd = null;
              isShowingAd = false;

              Log.d(LOG_TAG, "onAdFailedToShowFullScreenContent: " + adError.getMessage());
              Toast.makeText(activity, "onAdFailedToShowFullScreenContent", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT)
                  .show();

              onShowAdCompleteListener.onShowAdComplete();
              if (googleMobileAdsConsentManager.canRequestAds()) {
                loadAd(activity);
              }
            }

            /** Called when fullscreen content is shown. */
            @Override
            public void onAdShowedFullScreenContent() {
              Log.d(LOG_TAG, "onAdShowedFullScreenContent.");
              Toast.makeText(activity, "onAdShowedFullScreenContent", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            }
          });

      isShowingAd = true;
      appOpenAd.show(activity);
    }
  }
}



Still unable to implement this, can anyone help?
